# How to select nth child of specific tag with css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select the 4th `<p>` tag and hide it with CSS in the code below? (It has neither class property nor id)

```
<form id="registerform" name="registerform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=register" method="post">
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <style></style>
   <p></p>
   <p> //this tag
    <label>
      gen_code
      <br>
      <input id="gen_code" class="input" type="text" name="gen_code" value="" size="25" tabindex="20" style="font-size: 20px; width: 97%; padding: 3px; margin-right: 6px;">
    </label>
   </p>  
   <p class="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: [`:nth-of-type()`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) - IE9 and over. That said, the tag should *really* have a class for this.

Comment: That's the 5th element.

Comment: Seriously, why do you even have a `<style>` tag in the middle of your document body? (I'm guessing you're not using `scoped` because nobody does because it's not really supported by not-FF yet.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
form p:nth-of-type(4) {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rswK5/).

This will hide the fourth `p` element, rather than the fourth-child (which is important as, in your HTML, the `p` is the fifth-child).

And, just to demonstrate why `:nth-child()` is the wrong selector, here's a demo showing the use of `p:nth-child(4)`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rswK5/1/).

Incidentally, if that's the only element that contains a `label` (which, given that the elements are nested within a `form` seems an unlikely assumption), you could also use IE-friendly selectors:

```
p {
    /* removes the visible-space left by empty p elements */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

p > label {
    /* hides the label element, and its contents */
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rswK5/2).

References:

- [`:nth-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo).

Answer (score 3):

Use nth-of-type: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

```
form p:nth-of-type(4) {  
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: -1 I believe he wants the 4th `<p>` (as opposed to the 4th child)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support IE7-8, you may also use this (ugly:) quick workaround based on the general sibling selector:

```
form p ~ p ~ p ~ p {
    display: none;
}

form p ~ p ~ p ~ p ~ p {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-of-type()`, as other's have suggested, or try `:nth-child()`.

Here's an `:nth-child()` example:

```
#registerform p:nth-child(4n) { display: none; }
```

Comment: Except the `p` isn't the fourth-child, and `4n` would hide *every* fourth element. Which also doesn't seem to be required..?

Answer (score 1):

### To Accommodate Older Browsers

David Thomas's answer is perfect for any CSS3 enabled browsers (and deserves the accepted answer place). However, for some completeness, IE7-8 support could key in off of your `<style>` element like so (which would also work in later browsers):

```
form style + p + p {
    display: none;
}
```

This obviously assumes the structure you posted. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rswK5/4/).